# Mysql Sort order very Weird

Tags: mysql, utf-8, sql-order-by

```
SELECT events.title 
FROM events 
ORDER BY events.title DESC
```

I'm getting the proper ordering for all but a couple events at the end of my table.

The encoding on the title table is `utf8_general_ci`.  I've tried retyping the the title, hoping it was using some weird russian characters I couldn't see, but it still appears in the wrong order.

Comment: Unless you show us an example that wrong order, there's not much we can tell you.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the DDL for the table.  Run "SHOW CREATE TABLE events" and post the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a wild guess, but maybe some of your titles have some spaces at the beginning.

If that is your problem, you can use

```
Order By TRIM(events.title) DESC
```

But that will slow down your query because MySQL won't be able to use the index on title if you have one.

Comment: Good suggestion!  It may be helpful to run a query such as SELECT CONCAT('[', events.title, ']') FROM events to see if there are leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Ran `UPDATE events SET title = TRIM(title)` Worked like a charm thanks!

Comment: Good, I didn't propose the update because I didn't know if changing the data was an option.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please run

```
SELECT HEX(CAST(title AS BINARY))
FROM   events
WHERE  id = @weird_record
```

and post the output here?

**Update:**

It seems that the record is plain `ASCII`, no leading spaces of weird characters, and says `Walters Brothers Rebellion`

Could you please do the same for a recors which is out of order?

Please pick some record that should come before the `Walter Brothers` but comes after, of vice versa, and post the results of the same query.